# ListView adapter getView() not called if populated after onCreate()

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm having a rather puzzling problem. If I try to populate a ListView with an AsyncTask, getView() on that ListView's adapter is never called. Note that this is the initial population of data for this ListView when the Activity starts. The AsyncTask is needed as the ListView is populated from HTTP.

I have the following simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/transactionListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#CCCCCC"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And a basic onCreate():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transactionListView);
    this.populateListView();
}
```

Which you can see calls:

```
private void populateListView()
{
    populateListViewTask task = new populateListViewTask();
    task.execute();
}
```

And finally, the AsyncTask onPostExecute():

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    lvAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listitem, data);
    mainListView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
}
```

The actual implementation is a bit more complex than that, of course, but I've elimnated any other sources of errors except for getView() not being called in the above configuration. If add lvAdapter.getCount() in onPostExecute(), I get 30 (which is what I expect, as the HTTP/XML parsing part of the real code is working properly). I have also tried adding notifyDataSetChanged(), just for grins, but CustomArrayAdapter is, as the name suggests, extending ArrayAdapter. I have also tried invalidate() on the view, also to no effect.

However, if alter onCreate() to have a single dummy list item like so before calling the AsyncTask:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transactionListView);

    //Add dummy list item
    TestDataStructure[] data = new TestDataStructure[1];|
    data[0] = new TestDataStructure();
    data[0].item = "Dummy List Item";
    lvAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listitem, data);
    mainListView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);

    this.populateListView();
}
```

getView() will then be called properly after the onPostExecute() call, and the ListView will populate properly with the new items from the AsyncTask. My hunch is that in the original case, Android determines the structure and visibility of items in the layout during the Activity creation cycle, and decides that transactionListView is not visible as it is empty, thus preventing it from calling getView() when a new adapter is set.

Any ideas on how to fix this without adding the dummy list item (which is of course visible until the AsyncTask finishes)? My activity extends Activity, not ListActivity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is `ArrayList<String>`, you can assign in `onCreate()` this `data = new ArrayList<String>();` and assign the adapter with this, this will keep your ListView empty until you finish the asynctask, you can assign data with your values, and notify the adapter that the data has been changed with this `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is an array of objects, which getView() tries to act on as soon as I load up the dummy item. Therefore, I can't pass any null values into the data going to the Adapter.

Comment: @Nishmaster: Setting the adapter's data to `new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>()` while you're waiting on the AsyncTask to finish works just fine. As far as your specific problem, I put your example code into a dummy project and it seemingly ran without issues. I'm also doing something pretty much identical to what you're describing in my own project (ArrayAdapter with a custom object type and all) and haven't seen this issue, nor have I had the problem with notifyDataSetChanged() that you report. It's not a fun answer to hear, but perhaps the error stems from somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds and looks like you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adaptor after it has been populated.  This must be called from the UI thread, so put it into code directly called from the postExecute() method.

If this helps, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: If you note in my original question above, I have tried that with no success. I do not think that notifyDataSetChanged() has any effect on ArrayAdapters.